# Eclipse content-assist shows java method parameters only before I start typing

Tags: java, eclipse

As of recently, I am having a problem with eclipse content assist, which is driving me crazy.

when starting typing method parameters, eclipse typically shows the parameter names and types. "previously" that tooltip stayed open and showed me with a bold font, which parameter I am actually specifing.
However, recently this behaviour changed: I get that content assist tooltip only when I haven't entered any parameter. if I use auto-completion for e.g. a method-parameter, that parameter-list is gone forever - Ctrl+Space simply shows the available local variables.

1. after typing a method-name, the parameters are shown:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQSQl.png)
2. after using auto-completion (or some other popup, etc) which causes the parameter-list to disappear, pressing Ctrl+ doesn't bring it back. Instead I only get a list of local variables:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KEuB.png)

I would expect that the method parameter popup would re-appear on pressing Ctrl+

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> can be used to bring back the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

The popup you're missing is at `Edit` → `Content Assist` → `Parameter Hints`. You can change the binding in the Eclipse configuration if the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't feel natural.